# Get Tag values in array of checked items in android listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox, android-viewholder

This is my ContactsAdapter class from which am displaying the list with Checkbox. Here am able to get the Tag of checked items. There is another class FanFragment in which on click of a button(ContactList) I must get all the values of Tag in Array of checked items.

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends AbsAdapter {

TextView contactId = null;
TextView contactDesc = null;
static boolean checked[];
String[] arrPath;
int selectedCount;
CheckBox saveddesc;

public ContactsAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<RantModel> contenList) {
    super(activity, contenList);
}   

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    super.getView(position, convertview, parent);
    final ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertview == null){
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_row_layout, parent,
            false);
    try {
        holder.contactId = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tvListId);
        holder.contactDesc = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tvListName);
        holder.saveddesc = (CheckBox) convertview.findViewById(R.id.ckList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    convertview.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
    }


    holder.saveddesc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(((CompoundButton) v).isChecked()){

                String ale = (String) holder.saveddesc.getTag();

                System.out.println(ale);
            }
        }
    });

    RantModel ContactModel = mListContent.get(position);
    holder.contactDesc.setText(ContactModel.contactName);
    holder.contactId.setText(ContactModel.contactId);
    holder.saveddesc.setId(position);
    holder.saveddesc.setTag(ContactModel.contactId);
    holder.id = position;

    return convertview;
}

class ViewHolder{

    public int id;
    public CheckBox saveddesc;
    public TextView contactDesc;
    public TextView contactId;

}
```

FanFragment.class

```
public class FanFragment extends AbsFragment {

ContactsAdapter mFanContacts;
ArrayList<RantModel> mContactList;
String url;
ContactListService contactsWeb;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
private boolean checked[];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContactList = new ArrayList<RantModel>();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mContactList.removeAll(mContactList);
    listView.setAdapter(null);
    url = "";
    contactsWeb = new ContactListService();
    contactsWeb.execute();

    mFanthemContacts = new ContactsAdapter(mActivity, mContactList);
    listView.setAdapter(mFanthemContacts);

    //
     ContactList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }
     });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Worked for me. In the fragment do this on button click or what ever your trigger is.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < mContactList.getCount(); i++) {

                   View v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            Viewholder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
//Check condition for checkbox and insert into new array
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is that studentAttendanceHolder